# PostgreSQL Server Version Not Available in Preferences for Binary Path

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set the binary path so I can import csv files into a table, but the server version isn't listed.  Anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: You already have Postgres 14 selected, right?

Comment: What version of pgadmin4 is this?

Comment: @jjanes it's version 5.7

Comment: @TimRoberts no version is selected

Comment: I'm going to say pgAdmin4 version 5.7 is the issue given that it was released 2021-09-09 and Postgres 14 was released 2021-09-30.

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve.  The pgAdmin window in your screenshot has clearly connected to a server, because it has enumerated the databases.  If it's already connected, what are you trying to change?

Comment: Pro tip: If you encounter an issue with a years-old piece of software, try updating it first...

Comment: @TimRoberts, the issue is pgAdmin4 will connect or at least attempt to connect to a server that is newer then it 'knows about'. Whether you can do anything useful is another matter. What the OP wants to do is set a path for Postgres 14 and from the frame of reference of pgAdmin4 5.7 Postgres 14 does not exist yet so there is no option to do that.

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin4 only offers you to set paths for versions of PostgreSQL which existed (and probably which were in support) at the time the pgAdmin4 version was released.  So pgAdmin4 5.7 won't offer to set a path for PostgreSQL v14.  You need to update pgAdmin4 to something modern.